# Memory Analyze: Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code inside viewdidload:

```
NSMutableArray *children = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:childData];
self.childrenArray = [children copy];
```

Whenever i initialize object with new or copy, i have to release it right ? So when i analyze the code from xcode, it doesn't give me any memory warning for not releasing childrenArray, why so ? I am not releasing it on dealloc also just to check. I remember in many previous code it gave me warning when i was starting new. I am not using ARC.

Edit: I am using copy property, i.e @property(copy, nonatomic), I read that here synthesizer will copy the object instead of retain so does it have to do anything with this. My query is if synthesizer copy the object doesn't it increase the retain count of object, How is copy different from retain in this scenario context ? I need to understand this. Thanks

Thanks.

Comment: Did you profile your application for Allocations and Leaks?

Comment: I don't know, I am just using analyze as i used to always by going to Product -> Analyze, I am using xcode 4.3

Comment: This definitely appears to be a deficiency in the analyzer, but you need to try it in Xcode 4.4.1 before reporting it as a bug.  I tried your code in 4.4.1 and the analyzer correctly flagged it as a potential leak.

Comment: @robmayoff: I tried the code in 4.4.1 and the analyzer doesn't give any warnings. Strange.

Comment: @bloodwing: I removed my answer owing to the uncertainty over the issue.

Comment: @rob, just finished installing 4.4.1, yeah it was problem with 4.3, new xcode flags the warning. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in the analyzer.  Please file it.   Post the # of the bug here.  (Unless the latest version of Xcode/clang does flag it.)

Note that because you aren't using ARC, the analyzer might be assuming that you are being tricky.  I still think it should flag this, though.